# maven-checkstyle-plugin does not execute on custom rules

Tags: maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am trying to add in the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` like below as part of build check by following the official documentation. However I try, I couldn't get it to run with custom rules.

```html
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>validate</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The `checkstyle.xml` just contains the exact content as found in this [google_checks.xml](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml).

Upon executing `mvn checkstyle:check`, I always got hit by

```html
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.1.0:check (default-cli) on project XXXXXXX: Failed during checkstyle configuration: cannot initialize module LineLength - Property 'fileExtensions' does not exist, please check the documentation
```

Comment: Moving `LineLength` module into the `TreeWalker` module and completely removing the `fileExtensions` property line made it work...though this isn't really my intention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just having the same problem.
I see that the file have been changed 5 days ago.

You need to use file from the same version of checkstyle i.e for example for version 8.12 of checkstyle choose on git the branch with tag 8.12

https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/checkstyle-8.12/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

This file have the correct grammar definition for version 8.12 , last version of same file for example don't work with 8.12 version

Hope it help :)

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that the latest, v3.1.0 [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/) supports only the `checkstyle` version v8.19:

> This version of the plugin uses Checkstyle 8.19 by default and
>   requires Java 8. But you can upgrade the version used at runtime.

So you need to use the `checkstyle.xml` which belongs to `v9.19 checkstyle`.

**But the good news is that you can re-configure the maven plugin:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>...choose your version...</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

For more details, check the official [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html).